# Possible Textbook Error: Shouldn't $\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}} (-q,q) = \varnothing$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Example $A.14$ (from page $391$ of Paolo Aluffi's *Algebra: Notes from the Underground*) claims the following:

> **Example $A.14$:** For $q$ a nonnegative rational number, let $(-q,q)$ denote the open interval in the real line with endpoints $−q$ and $q$ (as in calculus!). You can view this as a set $S_q$ determined by the chosen $q \in \mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}$. (Here $\mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}$ denotes the set of nonnegative rational numbers.) Then you may verify that
> $$
> \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}} (-q,q) = \mathbb{R} \qquad
> \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}} (-q,q) = \{0\}
> $$

When $(-q,q)$ denotes the open interval in the real line... the smallest possible interval would then be $(-0,0)$ for which there is no element... right?

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman Did you read the question?

Comment: Yes, the intersection is the empty set, because $(-0,0)=\varnothing$ as you said. But, if you change $\Bbb Q^{\geq0}$ with $\Bbb Q^{>0}$, then is true.

Comment: I think you are right.  The intersection set should be empty.... Propably a typo,  or there instead of () should be [,] closed intervals....

Comment: Okay! Thank you... I thought I was going crazy. After toiling over attempting to verify this all day I arrived at the possibility the author made a typo and input the set containing 0 as opposed to the empty set.

Comment: That's possible, although I think it's more likely that the intersection was meant to be taken over $q \in \mathbb{Q}^{> 0}$, rather than $q \in \mathbb{Q}^{\geq 0}$, much as @azif00 said.

Comment: Ah okay, to me that is more plausible. Furthermore, in attempting to verify this that was one of the original proofs I worked on ... slowly my sanity is restoring

Comment: What is the textbook? Do they consider (0,0) an interval or (a,b) is considered an interval if a<b?

Comment: @mike this is Algebra: Notes from the Underground by Paulo Aluffi. I am reviewing Appendix A to ensure my foundational knowledge is sufficient. I'll double check but I believe the definition of an interval is left ambiguous. I have been interpreting (-q,q) as -q<x<q

Comment: All maths textbooks have this type of error somewhere unless the book is in it's tenth edition... even PMA has errors in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, this is indeed an error. Absent any other definition than

$$(a,b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x < b\}$$

then $(0,0) = \varnothing$, and since $0 \in \mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0} := \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x \ge 0\}$ and $X \cap \varnothing = \varnothing$ for any set $X$, then the intersection overall is empty.

Likewise, as mentioned in the comments:

- If we exclude $0$ from consideration, then the claim holds, since $-q < 0 < q$ for any $q > 0$.
- If we use closed intervals instead, the claim holds, since $0 \in \mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}$ means one of the intervals is $[0,0] = \{0\}$, obviously the smallest such interval.

---

*Largely just answering this to get it a proper "answer" in the sense of the site and remove it from the unanswered queue, leaving as Community Wiki since everything important so far was really in the comments.*

Comment: A contradiction argument seems unnecessary for the second point, just the fact that $0$ belongs to all these closed intervals and one of the intervals is itself $\{0\}$ will do.